# Extracting coordinates values using dict python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I really need help with this
I have JSON which i converted into dict and now i have to use keys to index my dictionary and extract 4 x and 4 y values

**1 of dict value looks like this. (I highlighted x and y values)**:

```
 {
    "objects": [
        {
            "featureId": "ckbrnqtf600jb0y6o1hsnanqj",
            "schemaId": "ckbrnnh4b009w0y5h4nend1n3",
            "title": "point",
            "value": "point",
            "color": "#FF0000",
            "point": {"x": 1262, "y": 161},
            "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckbrnqtf600jb0y6o1hsnanqj?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2JyaWh4b3JjYTBjMDc2Mml1OHR6Y3plIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2JyaWh4bnk0cnp1MDc3NjdmbmM1YXV4IiwiaWF0IjoxNTkyOTAzNDk0LCJleHAiOjE1OTU0OTU0OTR9.p1xWGMeXVJysOcYNjQbSHOlpnVdATkMwu-Ze-zm_wlg",
        },
        {
            "featureId": "ckbrnqwdw0fbq0z808cxg5dbl",
            "schemaId": "ckbrnnh4b009w0y5h4nend1n3",
            "title": "point",
            "value": "point",
            "color": "#FF0000",
            "point": {"x": 1320, "y": 162},
            "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckbrnqwdw0fbq0z808cxg5dbl?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2JyaWh4b3JjYTBjMDc2Mml1OHR6Y3plIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2JyaWh4bnk0cnp1MDc3NjdmbmM1YXV4IiwiaWF0IjoxNTkyOTAzNDk0LCJleHAiOjE1OTU0OTU0OTR9.p1xWGMeXVJysOcYNjQbSHOlpnVdATkMwu-Ze-zm_wlg",
        },
        {
            "featureId": "ckbrnqzfp00ji0y6ocz24ajah",
            "schemaId": "ckbrnnh4b009w0y5h4nend1n3",
            "title": "point",
            "value": "point",
            "color": "#FF0000",
            "point": {"x": 1278, "y": 205},
            "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckbrnqzfp00ji0y6ocz24ajah?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2JyaWh4b3JjYTBjMDc2Mml1OHR6Y3plIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2JyaWh4bnk0cnp1MDc3NjdmbmM1YXV4IiwiaWF0IjoxNTkyOTAzNDk0LCJleHAiOjE1OTU0OTU0OTR9.p1xWGMeXVJysOcYNjQbSHOlpnVdATkMwu-Ze-zm_wlg",
        },
        {
            "featureId": "ckbrnr2vx0fos0y84dgi1ck5s",
            "schemaId": "ckbrnnh4b009w0y5h4nend1n3",
            "title": "point",
            "value": "point",
            "color": "#FF0000",
            "point": {"x": 1328, "y": 210},
            "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckbrnr2vx0fos0y84dgi1ck5s?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2JyaWh4b3JjYTBjMDc2Mml1OHR6Y3plIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2JyaWh4bnk0cnp1MDc3NjdmbmM1YXV4IiwiaWF0IjoxNTkyOTAzNDk0LCJleHAiOjE1OTU0OTU0OTR9.p1xWGMeXVJysOcYNjQbSHOlpnVdATkMwu-Ze-zm_wlg",
        },
    ],
    "classifications": [],
}
```

```js
   import json 
json1_file = open('/content/export-2020-06-30T12_57_16.744Z.json')
 json1_str = json1_file.read() json1_data = json.loads(json1_str)

json1_data = json.loads(json1_str)[0]
       print("Type:", type(json1_data))
```

In the code I converted JSON into dict and now i have to extract values and save it in a row.
Please help with the code, how can i extract these x and y values.

Comment: I already gave an answer, but still wanted to ask you to code-format the input data. It is a bit scary this way ;-)

Comment: @Ronald 1st of all thanks alot for response. 2ndly, its giving me error of "string indices must be integers"

Comment: If you look at the input data, it ends with `..._wlg"}],"classifications":[]}`. Especially that last part, `,"classifications":[]}` does not belong to the dictionary within the list so I removed it. Without removing it, Python produces a syntax error. Are you sure you gave the correct input data?

Comment: It starts with {"objects":[{"featureId"..... and end on ....wlg"}],"classifications":[]}

Comment: Tsja, that was not in your post. But see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah, see that your post has been updated. It is much much better this way!

Answer (score 0):

That is not so difficult. I added the input data in shortened form:

```
dict= {"objects":[
{"featureId":"ckbrnqtf600jb0y6o1hsnanqj","schemaId":"ckbrnnh4b009w0y5h4nend1n3","title":"point","value":"point","color":"#FF0000",
    "point":{"x":1262,"y":161},"instanceURI":"https:"},
{"featureId":"ckbrnqwdw0fbq0z808cxg5dbl","schemaId":"ckbrnnh4b009w0y5h4nend1n3","title":"point","value":"point","color":"#FF0000",
    "point":{"x":1320,"y":162},"instanceURI":"https:"},
{"featureId":"ckbrnqzfp00ji0y6ocz24ajah","schemaId":"ckbrnnh4b009w0y5h4nend1n3","title":"point","value":"point","color":"#FF0000",
    "point":{"x":1278,"y":205},"instanceURI":"https:"},
{"featureId":"ckbrnr2vx0fos0y84dgi1ck5s","schemaId":"ckbrnnh4b009w0y5h4nend1n3","title":"point","value":"point","color":"#FF0000",
    "point":{"x":1328,"y":210},"instanceURI":"https:"}],"classifications":[]}

for d in dict["objects"]:
    x = d["point"]["x"]
    y = d["point"]["y"]
    print(x,y)
```

Outputs:

```
1262 161
1320 162
1278 205
1328 210
```

And as a list of tuples:

```
print([(d["point"]["x"], d["point"]["y"]) for d in dict["objects"]])
```

Outputs:

```
[(1262, 161), (1320, 162), (1278, 205), (1328, 210)]
```

**Looping over all dicts in the `json` file:**

Based on what I can derive from your posted code, it should be like this:

```
with open ('/content/export-2020-06-30T12_57_16.744Z.json', 'r') as jsonfile:
    json1_str = jsonfile.read()
json1_data = json.loads(json1_str)

for dict in json1_data:
    for d in dict["objects"]:
        x = d["point"]["x"]
        y = d["point"]["y"]
        print(x,y)           # demo, you may use it to create your own data strucure

# flat list of all (x,y) tuples of all dicts in the json file        
print([(d["point"]["x"], d["point"]["y"]) for d in dict["objects"] for dict in json1_data])
```

Comment: It worked!! Now the thing is I have 100 rows of such dicts. I have to extract points and save them in file/table/csv.

Comment: So the whole thing should be placed in a loop. How to create that loop, depends on your full source code, i.e. how the dicts are exactly being retrieved. It also matters how you want to store the x,y data. Could be for example in a flat list or in a nested list (one list per dict).

Comment: Correction, it depends also on how your json file was created. I tried a few things but I'm guessing. Is there a way you can show me you json file or a part (with more than 1, preferably 3 or 4 objects{}) of it?

Comment: I tried but can't send picture. It was created on labelbox.com

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects and each object has key-value pair for points and similarly you have key-value pairs of x and y, you can access it like this:

```
for object in objects:
    x = object["point"]["x"]
    y = object["point"]["y"]
    print("x = " + str(x) + " y = " + str(y))
```

Comment: how is this answer different from the answer already provided?